# Python - SQL: How do I insert these variables into a table in a database?

Tags: python, sql, database, variables, insert

the program must store these details in a table. I'm new to SQL and would like to know how to insert variables

```
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO userAcc(name, dob, age) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)'''(name1, dob1, age1))
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Please give a proper error description!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support the %s syntax as a placeholder (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). Use question marks instead, and don't forget to insert a comma after the SQL string:

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO userAcc(name, genre, artist) VALUES(?,?,?)''', (name1, genre1, artist1))
```